# Scoping without global variables in R

Tags: r, scope

I seem to be deeply confused about what constitutes good practice in R. Suppose that I have the following R code:

```
f<-function()  
{  
    g<-function(s)
    {
      b<-b+1
      s<-s+5
    }
b<-10
g(2)
return(b)
}
```

In any typical language, this will always return b=10 and to the best of my awareness, the typical way to get f to recognise that g is modifying b would be to use global variables. However, as best as I can tell, it seems to be common practice in R to avoid global variables wherever possible. This leads me to ask, how am I supposed to modify f so that it outputs b=11 without making any use of global variables? I seem to either have a very deep misunderstanding or to be ignorant of a very important idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three forms of the assignment operator in R:  `<-`, `=`, and `<<-`. The third form, `<<-`, assigns the value to an object in the parent of the current environment.

If you use this form in the `g()` function, it increments the value of `b` within the `f()` function by 1.

```
f<-function()  
{  
     g<-function(s)
     {
          # use <<- form instead of <- 
          b<<-b+1
          s<-s+5
     }
     b<-10
     g(2)
     return(b)
}
```

...and the output:

```
> f<-function()  
+ {  
+      g<-function(s)
+      {
+           b<<-b+1
+           s<-s+5
+      }
+      b<-10
+      g(2)
+      return(b)
+ }
> f()
[1] 11
>
```

Comment: "The third form, <<-, assigns the value to an object in the ***parent*** of the current environment" - I think that's exactly what I needed. Globals may be discouraged, but moving up one environment seems to not be.

Comment: @J.Mini - for additional background on how R handles lexical scoping, take a look at my blog post [R objects, S objects, and Lexical Scoping](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-lexicalScoping.md).